# In Ansible, how can I accept a WebSphere MQ licensing agreement as part of a playbook?

Tags: ibm-mq, ansible

I'm in the process of converting a manual server provisioning process into a Ansible playbook. Part of the process involves installing WebSphere MQ client. One step involves manually running a script, `mqlicense.sh`, and accepting a licensing agreement in response to a prompt. How can I accomplish this in Ansible?

If I run the script, the ansible process hangs. If I skip that step, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Product cannot be installed until the license
        agreement has been accepted.
        Run the 'mqlicense' script, which is in the root
        directory of the install media, or see the
        Quick Beginnings book for more information.
```

#### Update

Further Googling brought me to [this ibm.com page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009000_.htm), where it states:

> If want to accept the license without it being displayed, you can run
>   the mqlicense.sh script with the -accept option.
>
> `./mqlicense.sh -accept`

However, that does not seem to work in my case. When I run that command from the command line, the interactive prompt still comes up.

Comment: do you have a playbook avaliable somwhere?

Comment: @oluies I have located my playbook. I'll post a Github gist and add a link here as soon as I have the opportunity.

Comment: Find a Github gist with playbook here: https://gist.github.com/klenwell/cdf2dc92ddfe2e7e18fc. See comments at top of files for some caveats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with the mqlicense.sh script. Apparently, it uses some syntax incompatible with bash. So when I ran it on my Debian server, the script complained:

```
./mqlicense.sh: 99: ./mqlicense.sh: [[: not found
```

The solution, alluded to in [this ibm.com forum thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014567076), was to install the korn shell (`ksh`), and use that to accept the license. The following tasks were included in my playbook:

Include `ksh` with system packages:

```
- name: Install debian packages
  apt: pkg=${item} state=installed
  with_items:
    - alien
    - ksh
```

Call the script using `ksh`:

```
# Need to run this with ksh; script syntax is not bash-compliant
- name: Accept MQ Client license
  command: ksh mqlicense.sh -accept chdir=${vsphere_wd}
```

---

Ansible playbook can be found here:

- https://gist.github.com/klenwell/cdf2dc92ddfe2e7e18fc